# using configparser in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry, I am a newbie in Python and trying to work on the ConfigParser module. Here is one script which is used to read multiple sections and values from a .ini file and print them as below (Current output). Now, I would like to store each of these values of url, password into variables and use each of them to run REST call using a for loop.

What changes are required to store value of each "url" and "password" into different variables?

```
# cat file.ini

[bugs]
url = http://localhost:1010/bugs/
username = mark
password = SECRET

[wiki]
url = http://localhost:1010/wiki/
username = chris
password = PWD
```

Script :-

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('file.ini')

for element in parser.sections():
    print 'Section:', element
    print '  Options:', parser.options(element)
    for name, value in parser.items(element):
        print '  %s = %s' % (name, value)
    print
```

Current output :-

```
~]# python parse.py

Section: wiki
  Options: ['url', 'username', 'password']
  url = http://localhost:1010/wiki/
  username = chris
  password = PWD

Section: bugs
  Options: ['url', 'username', 'password']
  url = http://localhost:1010/bugs/
  username = mark
  password = SECRET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('file.ini')

config_dict = {}

for element in parser.sections():
    print 'Section:', element
    config_dict[element] = {}
    print '  Options:', parser.options(element)
    for name, value in parser.items(element):
        print '  %s = %s' % (name, value)
        config_dict[element][name] = value

print config_dict
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, how do I print the value of name "password" which is repeated twice in "config_dict"

Comment: Got it.. print config_dict[element]['password']

Answer (score 1):

```
# The format is parser.get(section, tag)
bugs_url = parser.get('bugs', 'url')
bugs_username = parser.get('bugs', 'username')
bugs_password = parser.get('bugs', 'password')

wiki_url = parser.get('wiki', 'url')
wiki_username = parser.get('wiki', 'username')
wiki_password = parser.get('wiki', 'password')
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas.. But I would like to store each value to the same variable (for example, store value of password to a single variable "password" from both sections and also irrespective of number sections mentioned in the .ini file (i.e not specifying the name of the section explicitly).