# Read specific text using configparser

Tags: python, configparser

I have an INI file that I want to read just the station name. The INI file looks like this below

```
[StationData]
StationName = "DPT11"

[Debug]
ProberTouchDown = "TRUE"
```

I had just learned that it would be easier to use configparser rather than pandas to parse this text file. I am hoping to just get the "DPT11" or DPT11. How would I do that?

I tried copying some examples on this question. Couldn't really figure it out though.
[using configparser in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885676/using-configparser-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python 3.10.6 try the following:

Script contents:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("src.ini")

for key, value in config["StationData"].items():
    print(value)
```

Output from `python3 script.py` should be:

```
"DPT11"
```